# Data is not fetched from sqlite database in iphone device but working in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my app I want to display data from sqlite database into UITableView.It is working fine in ios simulator but data is not fetched when using iphone device.I dont understand what the issue is.I have added Db.sqlite file into my project.Plz help me in solving this.My code is below:

```
+(BOOL)copyFile{ 
NSString *strSourcePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSString *strHome=NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *strDestPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/NewDb.sqlite",strHome];
NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *err;
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:strDestPath]==NO) {
    [manager copyItemAtPath:strSourcePath toPath:strDestPath error:&err];
    return YES;
}
else{
    NSLog(@"file already exists");
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

+(NSMutableArray*)getDetails{
NSString *strHome = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/NewDb.sqlite",strHome];
NSMutableArray *arrDetails=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *db;
int n = sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String], &db);
if (n==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *strQuery=@"SELECT * FROM Categories";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *err_msg;

    int res=sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &stmt, &err_msg);
    if (res == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories *categories=[[Categories alloc]init];
            categories.categoryId=sqlite3_column_int(stmt,0);
            categories.categoryName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            categories.categoryImage=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
            [arrDetails addObject:categories];

        }
    }
}
return arrDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it might be the problem what is happening to `images` displayed with `uppercase letters`, try changing your `sqlite` file into **lowercase letters**. like

```
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/newdb.sqlite",strHome];
```

Comment: if i make these changes app is crashing

Comment: delete the app from device then try

Answer (score 0):

Changes are as follows

```
+(BOOL)copyFile{ 
    //This needs to change
    NSString *strDestPath = [YourClassName dbPath];
}


+(NSMutableArray*)getDetails{
   //This needs to change
   NSString *strDestPath = [YourClassName dbPath];
}

+(NSString *)dbPath{

    return [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject] stringByAppendingString:@"NewDb.sqlite"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing **Db** by **db**

```
NSString *strSourcePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```